# How can I change/decrease the Android spinner size?

Tags: android, spinner

I'd like to decrease/change the spinner size which includes:

1. the spinner object size
2. the font displayed (its size and color)
3. When I open spinner the list view which is displayed (its font size and color)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can change these settings in the layout file. 
The hello-spinner tutorial is very useful.

http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html

Add a new XML file to your layout folder.

Example: spinnerLayout.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/spinnerTarget"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textSize="14pt"         
              android:textColor="#FF8B1500"
              android:gravity="center"/>
```

Change the adapter resource to your new layout file:

```
adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.sound, R.layout.spinnerLayout);
```

Comment: Yeah it changed the whole UI object size, but I want to customize the spinner. May be like using setDropDownResource, but I am not able to figure out how to make such resource.

Answer (score 9):

```
android:padding="0dip"
```

in my spinner makes it smaller using

```
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
```

when making the array adapter seems to make it smaller also, but i have no idea whether or not that is a sane thing to do.