# Change height of items Programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

### What I need to know

I need to know how can I change the height of any item (in this case it's a spinner).

### What is my program composed of

My program is composed of a Table having table rows (which are added pragmatically).

### What I want to achieve:

I want to make all items in every row of same height.

### What the Program does:

Every time you press the add button a TextView , Spinner , EditText are added inside a row which is also generated.

### Notes

P.S: If you know any other way (Not listed in "What I want to achieve") to achieve my goal just post it

### Image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you can either change your spinner's size so that it doesn't look huge compared to the other elements (see [How can I change/decrease the Android spinner size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927012/how-to-change-decrease-android-spinner-size)) or change the alignment of your items (see [Android View align bottom (programmatically) without XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563163/android-view-align-bottom-programmatically-without-xml)), for example align the bottom of your spinner with your EditText's

Answer (score 0):

You change the dimensions of a View in code using setLayoutParams():

```
myView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(widthInPx, heightInPx));
```

In this example, the parent of the view is a LinearLayout. If you are using a table, you're probably looking for TableRow.LayoutParams.

See this post for more on this topic: [How to resize a custom view programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963152/android-how-to-resize-a-custom-view-programmatically)